# LESS Loop error when using Grunt + Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, loops, twitter-bootstrap-3, gruntjs, less

This is my loop:

```
@loop-start: 1;
@loop-end: 20;
.loop(@n, @i) when (@n =< @loop-end) {
  .testi-square:nth-of-type(@{n}) {order: (@i);}
  .testi-square:nth-of-type(@{n + 1}) {order: (@i + 1);}
  .testi-square:nth-of-type(@{n + 2}) {order: (@i + 2);}

  .loop((@n + 3), (@i + 6)); // next iteration
}
.loop(@loop-start, @loop-start); // launch the loop
```

And this is the error I get:

```
Running "less:compileThemeWeb" (less) task
ParseError: Missing closing ')' in less/theme-web.less on line 3630, column 29:
3629   .testi-square:nth-of-type(@{n}) {order: (@i);}
3630   .testi-square:nth-of-type(@{n + 1}) {order: (@i + 1);}
3631   .testi-square:nth-of-type(@{n + 2}) {order: (@i + 2);}
Warning: Error compiling less/theme-web.less Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

I'm using the latest Bootstrap to create my theme. I've been using this for the past 6 months with no issues, I doubt the version of LESS is too old. Not sure how to resolve the issue, seems like a syntax thing but not sure. Been staring at http://lesscss.org/features/#loops-feature all day and scouring the internet but no dice.

Comment: `nth-of-type(@{n + 1})` - this is not valid Less code. You can't use expressions or anything else (function calls etc. etc) withing selector interpolation, only pure variables e.g. `@{n}` are valid, `@{n + 1}` is not.

Comment: Sorry @seven-phases-max. Posted an answer before seeing your comment. Think you should have posted your comment also as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is because of the following lines:

```css
.testi-square:nth-of-type(@{n + 1}) {order: (@i + 1);}
.testi-square:nth-of-type(@{n + 2}) {order: (@i + 2);}
```

When the compiler encounters the `@{n + 1}`, it would be looking for a variable named `n + 1`. You don't have any such variables named `n + 1` (and it is not valid syntax either). So, it would result in compilation error. The fix would be to use something like this:

```css
@loop-start: 1;
@loop-end: 20;
.loop(@n, @i) when (@n =< @loop-end) {
  .testi-square:nth-of-type(@{n}) {order: (@i);}
  @temp: @n + 1;
  .testi-square:nth-of-type(@{temp}) {order: (@i + 1);}
  @temp2: @n + 2;
  .testi-square:nth-of-type(@{temp2}) {order: (@i + 2);}

  .loop((@n + 3), (@i + 6)); // next iteration
}
.loop(@loop-start, @loop-start); // launch the loop
```

As stated by seven-phases-max in his comment, we can't use expressions, function calls etc within selector interpolation. Only variables are allowed.